# Failed responsive navbar

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, navbar

I have a navigation bar which I want it only has the first element `Wakanda Team` and a burger icon when the screen goes smaller than 900px. But I keep getting other elements appear like in the picture. Can anyone help?

[image]

HTML:

```
 <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <li style="float:left"><a href="#home" class="home">Wakanda Team</a></li>
    <li><a><i class="material-icons">subdirectory_arrow_left</i> Sign out</a></li>
    <li><a><i class="material-icons">exit_to_app</i> Sign in</a></li>
    <li><a><i class="material-icons">person_add</i> Register</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a></li>
  </ul>
      <p>Welcome to <%= title %></p>
  <script>
      function myFunction() {
          var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
          if (x.className === "topnav") {
              x.className += " responsive";
          } else {
              x.className = "topnav";
          }
      }
  </script>
```

CSS:

```
 ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

li {
    float: right;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.home){
    background-color: #111;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

li a .home:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.material-icons {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.topnav .icon {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
    .topnav a.icon {
        float: right;
        display: block;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
    .topnav.responsive .icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
    .topnav.responsive a {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }
}
```

Comment: This: .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;} 

The "a" tag is always the first child as it is wrapped in an "li". So it's the first child in its wrapper.

If you want to do it this way it has to be like: .topnav li:not(:first-child) a {display: none;}

Also add "li" to the next line so it will overwrite it. Like this: .topnav li a.icon..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try  this one**

```js
function myFunction() {
          var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
          if (x.className === "topnav") {
              x.className += " responsive";
          } else {
              x.className = "topnav";
          }
      }
```

```css
 ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

li {
    float: right;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.home){
    background-color: #111;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

li a .home:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.material-icons {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.topnav .icon {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .topnav li:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
 }
 .topnav li.icon {
  display: block;
 }
    .topnav a.icon {
        float: right;
        display: block;
    }
}
```

```html
<ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <li style="float:left"><a href="#home" class="home">Wakanda Team</a></li>
    <li><a><i class="material-icons">subdirectory_arrow_left</i> Sign out</a></li>
    <li><a><i class="material-icons">exit_to_app</i> Sign in</a></li>
    <li><a><i class="material-icons">person_add</i> Register</a></li>
    <li class="icon"><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a></li>
  </ul>
      <p>Welcome to <%= title %></p>
```

Comment: Thanks, Anzil, the burger does appear but when I click on it, nothing happens. The p tag doesn't appear either. You can see it when running code snippet too.